# Live audio recording and playing with 2 raspberry pis

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, raspberry-pi

I have a request...

I want to put a live audio with a transmitter a receiver, of course, I go through a server to link the two. I use for that [socket.io](https://socket.io/docs/) and [nodejs](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/)
I want to be able to read it on the web and mobile

But here is the problem - I do not know how to generate an audio stream that I can send then read it at the same time.

My environements:

- **Server**:

  ```
  let socket = require('socket.io')(4000)

  socket.on('connection', function(client) {
      client.on('audio', function(data){
          client.broadcast.emit('emit', data)
      })
  })
  ```

---

- **Transmitter**(raspberry pi 3) :

  ```
  let socket = require('socket.io-client')('http://my_server')

  socket.on('connection', function(server) {
      server.emit('audio',{recorder: 'output_audio'})
  })
  ```

---

- **Receiver** (raspberry pi 3):

  ```
  let socket = require('socker.io-client')('http://my_server')

  socket.on('connection', function(server) {
      server.on('emit', function(data) {
          // read and play audio received
      })
  })
  ```

---

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I want to know, how to record audio and in same time play it.